approval for adding figures for comparison into our own publications in phy/eng fields
In physical and engineering sciences it is common to compare with figures generated by other publications. Then it's said we need to get people's approval when adding their figures into our own publications. For example, for comparing theoretical and experimental data I wonder why we need this approval. This is so common and if we need to do it all the time it is quite annoying and time consuming especially when we need to compare with different publications then imagine that we need to contact multiple people for approval for our own publication.
Why can't we just cite their publication and say that this figure is from their publication?
Is asking people's approval for inserting their figure restricted to the scenario when we need to reproduce a figure for example superimposing their figure with our own then we need their approval or do we need approval for just adding their original figure without changing the contents at all?

Do you mean if we only need to reproduce the data without reproducing the image we don't need to ask for their approval?

Citations get you "academic" permission; acknowledging the ideas of others permits you to use them. This is the backbone of shared human knowledge, we wouldn't get anywhere without it.
When you reuse a figure, you're not asking for academic permission, you're asking for copyright permission. In the olden days, this was primarily getting permission from a journal who had exclusive rights to print that figure.
These days, though, a lot of things are release with more permissive licenses like Creative Commons licenses. These would permit you to reuse without asking permission, as long as you follow all the rules for use under that license, which often includes releasing your own work based on it under the same license.
If something is released under such a license and you can comply with the terms, then the innovation you're looking for already exists.

Thank you. Can I understand this way? If I need to publish my papers with these reproduced images I need to get the copyright for publishing them in more or less the original form then I need to ask for the permission from the original authors?  Then in the other case where I don't need to reproduce their images but I just need to use their published data, do I still need their permission?

@feynman Most often you would actually need permission from the journal, who likely has at least a semi exclusive license from the authors for the figures. But yes you could start by asking the authors. Just using public data does not require permission. Take meta analyses, for example; these take estimates from many studies and combine them in a principled way. For a meta analysis to be valid it's crucial to include all possible studies, and it's definitely not required to get permission from the authors.
